# array splice doesn't fire ngOnChange

Tags: javascript, angular

ngOnChange got fired when I add items to the array:

```
this.entries = [{"name": "John"},{"name": "Alex"},{"name": "Joe"}]
```

but not fired when I remove an item like this:

```
this.entries.splice(this.entries.findIndex(x => x.name === "Joe"), 1);
```

The item is really removed because the array size is changed.

```
Component code:
@Component({
  selector: ‘app-component’,
  …
})

export class InputComponent {
  @Input() entries:any=[];

  ngOnChanges() {
    console.log(this.entries);
  }
}

HTML:
<app-component [entries] = "entries"></app-component>

Update function:
removeEntry(key:string) {
    this.entries.splice(this.entries.findIndex(x => x.name === key), 1);
}
```

How do I fix it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could use filter instead of splice:

```
removeEntry(key:string) {
  this.entries =  this.entries.filter(x => x.name !== key);
}
```

For the sake of completeness, the reason you have to reassign the variable is that the filter method does not modify the existing array, but rather it returns a new array with the filtered elements.

Answer (score 0):

I am not angular expert too, I'm learning. What I understood by your wrote, when you remove something item in array, you need create new variable to remove item, and then set again, so it calls event to refresh, I think it's this.
This is an example:

```
let newPhotos = this.photos.slice(0);
let index = newPhotos.indexOf(photo);
newPhotos.splice(index, 1);
this.photos = newPhotos;
```

Can you try and tell me if it's worked?
And you can try using FILTER!
Thanks and sorry for my knowledge and english!